# Integration by substitution, from one dimension to two.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm looking to prove the following equation:
$$\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-T}^T \Big(1-\frac{|t|}{T}\Big)e^{-ixt}\phi(t)dt
= \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\int_0^Te^{-i(t-s)x}\phi(t-s)dt ds\tag{$\star$}$$
where $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a positive definite continuous absolutely  integrable function (but I'm not sure if this is necessary for the above equation to hold) and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed.

This is a step in a proof of Bochner's theorem, namely, if $\phi(t)$ is positive definite and $\phi(0)=1$ then $\phi(t)$  is the characteristic function of some probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}$.

The argument given for $(\star)$ is "a change of variables shows equation $(\star)$," but I'm having trouble seeing how it's so. Mostly given that all the theorems I know (from measure theory) for changes of variables involve transformations from sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so that the Frechet derivative of the transformation is a square matrix and has a determinant (Jacobian).

One of the theorems I found in wikipedia that seemed most promising was:
[image: Integration by substituion, wikipedia]
perhaps taking $\varphi$ to be $\varphi:[0,T]^2\rightarrow[-T,T]$ defined by $(t,s)\mapsto t-s$, but I'm not sure if this is the correct direction to head in and I'm getting tied up in knots.

I'd appreciate any help in showing $(\star)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the RHS and making the change of variable $u = t-s$ with $t$ fixed, we get
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^T dt \int_0^T e^{-i(t-s)x} \phi(t-s)\, ds &= \int_0^T dt \int_{t-T}^t e^{-iux} \phi(u)\, du\\
&=\int_{-T}^T e^{-iux} \phi(u)\,du \int_0^T \mathbf{1}_{t-T \leq u \leq t} \, dt, \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
where in the second equality I used Fubini's theorem. Now the inner integral is simply equal to
$$\int_0^T \mathbf{1}_{ u \leq t\leq u+T} \, dt = \operatorname{Leb}\big([0,T]\cap [u,u+T]\big)= \begin{cases}\operatorname{Leb}([u,T]) = T-u & \text{if } u \in [0,T], \\
\operatorname{Leb}([0,T+u]) = T+u & \text{if } u \in [-T,0).
\end{cases}$$
That is $\int_0^T \mathbf{1}_{u\leq t \leq u+T} \, dt = T - \lvert u \rvert$. Reinjecting in $(1)$, we get the desired equality.

Comment: Wow I feel like it's quite a gap to leave to the reader! I would've never figured it out. Is this a common trick? Thanks!